# Django - How to create a dictionary containing every word of a TextField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, textfield

How do I go about transforming a Django `TextField` into a dictionary containing all the words in the field?

I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work (no errors, but don't see anything in my template or the shell):

```
def song_words():
    result = Song.objects.filter(pk=request.pk).values_list('lyrics_ru',flat=True)
    r_list =[]
    for r in result:
        r_list.append(r.split())
    return r_list
```

I also tried:

```
def get_word(self):
    dict_value = getattr(self, 'lyrics_ru_dict', None)
    if not dict_value:
        import json
        dict_value = json.loads(self.lyrics_ru)
        setattr(self, 'lyrics_ru_dict', dict_value)
    return dict_value

def set_word(self, new_lyrics_ru):
    import json
    self.lyrics_ru = json.dumps(new_lyrics_ru).encode('utf8')
    self.lyrics_ru_dict = dict(new_lyrics_ru)

word = property(get_word, set_word)
```

But I get the following error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. I don't have any experience with json, and I have no idea if this is the right way to go.

This is my model:

```
class Song(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
   artist = models.CharField(max_length=25)
   url = models.URLField()
   lyrics_ru = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
   lyrics_gb = models.TextField(max_length=1500)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

My end goal is that I want to compare the words contained in `lyrics_ru` with the words (specifically, `target_word`) in a different model:

```
class Word(models.Model):

    target_word = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    source_word = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

The problem is that I have no idea whether I am on the right track or not. So if somebody can provide some advice / links, I would be very grateful!

Comment: What is your expected result (the dict form) if you have a text data as ***this is my test lyrics_ru data***

Comment: if you want to perform a search operation in the text field, use `icontains` lookup as, **`Song.objects.filter(lyrics_ru__icontains='your search keyword')`**

Comment: @ArakkalAbu so can 'your search keyword' be a field of a different model? Like for example `word__target_word`? Say for example my lyrics are: "This is a song", I want the dictionary to be ['This', 'is', 'a', 'song']

Comment: the representation *`['This', 'is', 'a', 'song']`* is not a `dict`, it is **`list`**

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Whoops, I guess I want a list then, does it change the approach?

Answer (score 0):

If u want the lyrics to be list of diffrent words what u can simply do is

```
words = text.split()
```

As of the other part from your description is you want to compare the data of `lyrics_ru` with `target_word` and want the count of word occurrence (assuming).
So what u can do is

```
from collections import Counter
def matching_words():
    match = []
    result = Song.objects.values_list('lyrics_ru',flat=True).filter(pk=request.pk)
    target_word = Word.objects.values_list('target_word')
    for i in result:
        if i in target_word:
            match.append(i)       # list of matching words
    finaldict = Counter(match)     # make dictonary of count
```

Comment: Would this go in my model or views, and how would I use it in my template?

Comment: I've used `{{song.matching_words}}` in my template, but nothing appears.

Comment: The above code will go in your `views` , U can use this function when u submit the form. And to display them in your template u have to pass the dictonary at the time of redirect.  refer the documentation [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/)